# Android Development in Eclipse Unrechable Code Intent

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent

For practice I make the example "Building your first app" on https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html
Now I have problem with Intents. Eclipse say "Unreachable Code" I have already imported the class Intent (import android.content.Intent;)

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
```

Here is the code:

```
package com.example.test;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.os.Build;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DisplayMessageActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);
    // Show the Up button in the action bar.
    setupActionBar();
}

/**
 * Set up the {@link android.app.ActionBar}, if the API is available.
 */
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
private void setupActionBar() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.display_message, menu);
    return true;
    // Get the message from the intent
    **Intent intent = getIntent();**
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    //Create the text view
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setText(message);

    //Set the Text view as the activity layout
    setContentView(textView);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        // This ID represents the Home or Up button. In the case of this
        // activity, the Up button is shown. Use NavUtils to allow users
        // to navigate up one level in the application structure. For
        // more details, see the Navigation pattern on Android Design:
        //
        // http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html#up-vs-back
        //
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Comment: write return statement in the last in onCreateOptionsMenu();

Comment: Read this if you are not familiar how return statement works. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can't be reached because you `return` in the line before.

```
return true;
// Get the message from the intent
**Intent intent = getIntent();**
```

Remove the return statement (make it the last thing you do in that method) or make it conditional.

Answer (score 0):

Update your `onCreateOptionsMenu` method like this, **return** must be the last line of code you write in any Method. Post `return` statement the method does not execute anything.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.display_message, menu);

    // Get the message from the intent
    **Intent intent = getIntent();**
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    //Create the text view
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setText(message);

    //Set the Text view as the activity layout
    setContentView(textView);
    // last statement for any method
    return true;
}
```

Comment: is it really necessary answering such a basic question with 4 identical answers

Comment: @smitalm No its not necessary, Sometimes you just cannot check if there is any other answer posted while writing your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.display_message, menu);

    // Get the message from the intent
    **Intent intent = getIntent();**
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    //Create the text view
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setText(message);

    //Set the Text view as the activity layout
    setContentView(textView);
return true;
}
```

Comment: is it really necessary answering such a basic question with 4 identical answers

Comment: @smitalm Brother the point is that while anybody answer the question don`t know is it given or not thats why .....

Comment: i agree with Ravind Maurya